# ServiceStack auto query - How to ignore a property in class

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've been testing ServiceStack auto query, which I really like so far. However, I've come across one issue. All of my service request DTOs have two properties from an interface named ILoggedRequest, which are used to log information about every request into a database using an implementation of IRequestLogger.

```
#region ILoggedRequest
public string Identifier
{
    get { return Id.ToString(); }
}
public string RequestClass
{
    get { return GetType().Name; }
}
#endregion
```

When these properties are included, since they contain values, Auto query tries to search for them and I get no results back from the request. Is there a way to decorate the properties so that Auto Query ignores them? Something like:

```
[QueryIgnore]
public string Identifier
{
    get { return Id.ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a repro as AutoQuery already ignores [Unknown/Ignored properties](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/40a7c39b5dac14aa600c76b804de17c18362a8a0). Can't tell what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks mythz for the quick response. Your reply raised suspicions and I double checked my db schema by switching sqlite to a file in the unit tests. Sure enough, my "Identifier" column was in the schema and so was not unknown. My apologies for wasting your time!

Comment: For others who come across this question, my "Identifier" column was not tagged with the [Ignore} attribute. I assumed, always a mistake, that a property that only had a getter would not be pushed to the db schema when using DropAndCreateTable.

Comment: ok great glad you found it. Best to add your comment as an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks mythz for the quick response. Your reply raised suspicions and I double checked my db schema by switching sqlite to a file in the unit tests. Sure enough, my "Identifier" column was in the schema and so was not unknown. My apologies for wasting your time!

For others who come across this question, my "Identifier" column was not tagged with the [Ignore} attribute. I assumed, always a mistake, that a property that only had a getter would not be pushed to the db schema when using DropAndCreateTable.

Comment: Remember to select you answer as the accepted answer :)